# How to render depth linearly in modern OpenGL with gl_FragCoord.z in fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, depth, depth-buffer

I read lots of information about getting depth with fragment shader.

such as

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=234519

but I still don't know whether or not the `gl_FragCoord.z` is linear.

GLSL specification said its range is [0,1] in screen sapce without mentioning it's linear or not.

I think linearity it is vital since I will use the rendered model to match depth map from Kinect.

Then if it is not linear, how to linearlize it in the world space?

Answer (score 39):

> but I still don't know whether or not the gl_FragCoord.z is linear.

Whether `gl_FragCoord.z` is linear or not depends on, the projection matrix.
While for Orthographic Projection `gl_FragCoord.z` is linear, for Perspective Projection it is not linear.

In general, the depth (`gl_FragCoord.z` and `gl_FragDepth`) is calculated as follows (see [GLSL gl_FragCoord.z Calculation and Setting gl_FragDepth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264949/glsl-gl-fragcoord-z-calculation-and-setting-gl-fragdepth)):

```
float ndc_depth = clip_space_pos.z / clip_space_pos.w;
float depth = (((farZ-nearZ) * ndc_depth) + nearZ + farZ) / 2.0;
```

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. It transforms from eye space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with the *w* component of the clip coordinates

#### Orthographic Projection

At Orthographic Projection the coordinates in the eye space are linearly mapped to normalized device coordinates.

[image: Orthographic Projection]

Orthographic Projection Matrix:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far 

2/(r-l)         0               0               0
0               2/(t-b)         0               0
0               0               -2/(f-n)        0
-(r+l)/(r-l)    -(t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    1
```

At Orthographic Projection, the Z component is calculated by the **linear function**:

```
z_ndc = z_eye * -2/(f-n) - (f+n)/(f-n)
```

[image: Orthographic Z function]

#### Perspective Projection

At Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport. 
 The eye space coordinates in the camera frustum (a truncated pyramid) are mapped to a cube (the normalized device coordinates).

[image: Perspective Projection]

Perspective Projection Matrix:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far

2*n/(r-l)      0              0               0
0              2*n/(t-b)      0               0
(r+l)/(r-l)    (t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    -1    
0              0              -2*f*n/(f-n)    0
```

At Perspective Projection, the Z component is calculated by the **rational function**:

```
z_ndc = ( -z_eye * (f+n)/(f-n) - 2*f*n/(f-n) ) / -z_eye
```

[image: Perspective Z function]

#### Depth buffer

Since the normalized device coordinates are in range (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1) the Z-coordinate has to be mapped to the depth buffer range [0,1]:

```
depth = (z_ndc + 1) / 2
```

> Then if it is not linear, how to linearize it in the world space?

To convert form the depth of the depth buffer to the original Z-coordinate, the projection (Orthographic or Perspective), and the near plane and far plane has to be known.

*Orthographic Projection*

```
n = near, f = far

z_eye = depth * (f-n) + n;
```

*Perspective Projection*

```
n = near, f = far

z_ndc = 2.0 * depth - 1.0;
z_eye = 2.0 * n * f / (f + n - z_ndc * (f - n));
```

If the perspective projection matrix is known this can be done as follows:

```
A = prj_mat[2][2]
B = prj_mat[3][2]
z_eye = B / (A + z_ndc)
```

See also the answer to

[How to recover view space position given view space depth value and ndc xy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277501/how-to-recover-view-space-position-given-view-space-depth-value-and-ndc-xy/46118945#46118945)

Comment: How did you make the diagrams?

Comment: @Makogan [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/?redirect=soft) Drawing -> Export PNG. (or [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)). The math functions I have plotted with a WebGL application, which I have programmed myself https://rabbid76.github.io/graphics-snippets/html/tools/function_plotter.html

Answer (score 12):

Assuming a usual perspective projection matrix, once the perspective division (by `gl_Position.w`) step is performed the depth loses its linearity, so `gl_FragCoord.z` is not linear. For a more detailed explanation read [@Dreamer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299656/2430597).

To revert back to linear you should perform 2 steps:

1) Transform the variable `gl_FragCoord.z` to normalized devices coordinates in the range [-1, 1]

```
z = gl_FragCoord.z * 2.0 - 1.0
```

2) Apply the inverse of the projection matrix (IP). (You can use arbitrary values for x and y), and normalize for the last component.

```
unprojected = IP * vec4(0, 0, z, 1.0)
unprojected /= unprojected.w
```

you will obtain a point in view space (or camera space, you name it) that has a linear z between znear and zfar.

Answer (score 4):

Whether `gl_FragCoord.z` is linear or not depends on **your** transformation matrix. `gl_FragCoord.z` is determined by computing `gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w` for all vertices of your triangle and then interpolating the result over all fragments of that triangle.

So `gl_FragCoord.z` is linear when your transformation matrix assigns a constant value to `gl_Position.w` (which usually happens with **ortho** projection matrices) and is non-linear when `gl_Position.w` depends on the `x`, `y`, or `z` coordinate of your input vector (which happens with **perspective** projection matrices).

Answer (score 3):

Its up to you to decide if you want linear Z or not, everythings relies on your projection matrix. You may read this:

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Which explains very well how projection matrices works. It may be better to have non-linear Z in order to have better precision in the foreground and less in the backgrounds, depth artifacts are less visible when far away...

Comment: thanks for that excellent site, however it is also necessary to confirm that how the specific variable works in GLSL. except the theory explanation I wanted a certain answer.

Comment: Well, GLSL handles floating point numbers, so any value is accepted. However, once your coordinates are projected, range [-1, 1] corresponds to the visible part of the screen for X and Y axis, and Z-buffer accepts [-1, 1] values, so any value outside this range may be clamped.

Comment: That's not true. As soon as you use a perspective projection, your projection matrix has to set the `w` coordinate of the output vector to the negative `z` coordinate of the input vector to facilitate the perspective foreshortening. And as soon as you do that there is no way to keep linear depth after transformation (since `x, y` **and** `z` will be divided by that negative `z` value in the perspective divide pipeline step).