# Depth offset in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, depth-buffer

What would be the best way of offsetting depth in OpenGL? I currently have index vertex attribute per polygon which I am passing to the Vertex Shader in OpenGL. My goal is to offset the polygons in depth where the highest index would be always in-front of the lower index. I currently have this simple approach modifying `gl_Position.z`.

```
gl_Position.z += -index * 0.00001;
```

Comment: Your approach should be fine when your goal is to have a different depth value for every polygon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual way to set an automatic offset for the depth is [`glPolygonOffset(GLfloat factor,GLfloat units)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonOffset.xhtml)

> When `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL`, `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE`, or `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_POINT` is enabled,
>   each fragment's depth value will be offset after it is interpolated from the depth values of the appropriate vertices.
>   The value of the offset is `factor * DZ + r * units`,
>   where `DZ` is a measurement of the change in **depth relative to the screen area** of the polygon,
>   and `r` is the smallest value that is **guaranteed to produce a resolvable offset** for a given implementation.
>   The offset is added before the depth test is performed and before the value is written into the depth buffer.

```
glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL );
glPolygonOffset( 1.0, 1.0 );
```

If you want to manually manipulate the depth then you have to set `gl_FragDepth` inside the fragment shader.

[gl_FragDepth](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml), [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader):

> Available only in the fragment language, `gl_FragDepth` is an output variable that is used to establish the depth value for the current fragment.
>   If depth buffering is enabled and no shader writes to `gl_FragDepth`, then the fixed function value for depth will be used
>   (this value is contained in the z component of `gl_FragCoord`) otherwise, the value written to `gl_FragDepth` is used.

In general, `gl_FragDepth` is calculated as follows (see [GLSL gl_FragCoord.z Calculation and Setting gl_FragDepth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264949/glsl-gl-fragcoord-z-calculation-and-setting-gl-fragdepth)):

```
float ndc_depth = clip_space_pos.z / clip_space_pos.w;
gl_FragDepth    = (((farZ-nearZ) * ndc_depth) + nearZ + farZ) / 2.0;
```

The minimum offset you need to add or subtract to the depth to get a minimum difference depends on the format of the depth buffer.

The depth buffer formats `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16`, `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` and `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32` are a normalized integer formats,
where the 16, 24 or 32 bit integer range is maped onto the depth values [0, 1].

On the other hand, the format `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F` is a IEEE 754 standard 32 bit floating point format.

Comment: Would that work between different batches? Is there a shader approach that would work?

Comment: It doesn't work between different batches. Can you provide alternative solution with shader?

Comment: The depth buffer isn't concerned with what wrote to it. I'd try rendering it as an overlay (or using a GPU debugger) to make sure the values are OK after your first pass.

Comment: The idea is to offset the depth for OIT between different batches of overlapping polygons using the index uniform.