# How to recover view space position given view space depth value and ndc xy

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, coordinate-transformation, perspectivecamera

I am writing a deferred shader, and am trying to pack my gbuffer more tightly. However, I cant seem to compute the view position given the view space depth correctly

```c
// depth -> (gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(pos.xyz, 1)).z; where pos is the model space position
// fov -> field of view in radians (0.62831855, 0.47123888)
// p -> ndc position, x, y [-1, 1]
vec3 getPosition(float depth, vec2 fov, vec2 p)
{
    vec3 pos;
    pos.x = -depth * tan( HALF_PI - fov.x/2.0 ) * (p.x);
    pos.y = -depth * tan( HALF_PI - fov.y/2.0 ) * (p.y);
    pos.z = depth;
    return pos;
}
```

The computed position is wrong. I know this because I am still storing the correct position in the gbuffer and testing using that.

Comment: What space do you expect the returned position to be in?

Comment: I expect it to be in view space

Comment: The computation forumla was cribbed off here http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/01gdc09ad3ddstalkerclearsky210309.ppt

Answer (score 17):

### 3 Solutions to recover view space position in perspective projection

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. It transforms from view (eye) space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with the *w* component of the clip coordinates. The NDC are in range (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1).

At Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport.
The eye space coordinates in the camera frustum (a truncated pyramid) are mapped to a cube (the normalized device coordinates).

[image]

Perspective Projection Matrix:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far

2*n/(r-l)      0              0               0
0              2*n/(t-b)      0               0
(r+l)/(r-l)    (t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    -1    
0              0              -2*f*n/(f-n)    0
```

it follows:

```
aspect = w / h
tanFov = tan( fov_y * 0.5 );

prjMat[0][0] = 2*n/(r-l) = 1.0 / (tanFov * aspect)
prjMat[1][1] = 2*n/(t-b) = 1.0 / tanFov
```

At Perspective Projection, the Z component is calculated by the **rational function**:

```
z_ndc = ( -z_eye * (f+n)/(f-n) - 2*f*n/(f-n) ) / -z_eye
```

The depth (`gl_FragCoord.z` and [`gl_FragDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml)) is calculated as follows:

```
z_ndc = clip_space_pos.z / clip_space_pos.w;
depth = (((farZ-nearZ) * z_ndc) + nearZ + farZ) / 2.0;
```

#### 1. Field of view and aspect ratio

Since the projection matrix is defined by the field of view and the aspect ratio it is possible to recover the viewport position with the field of view and the aspect ratio. Provided that it is a symmetrical perspective projection and the normalized device coordinates, the depth and the near and far plane are known.

Recover the Z distance in view space:

```
z_ndc = 2.0 * depth - 1.0;
z_eye = 2.0 * n * f / (f + n - z_ndc * (f - n));
```

Recover the view space position by the XY normalized device coordinates:

```
ndc_x, ndc_y = xy normalized device coordinates in range from (-1, -1) to (1, 1):

viewPos.x = z_eye * ndc_x * aspect * tanFov;
viewPos.y = z_eye * ndc_y * tanFov;
viewPos.z = -z_eye;
```

#### 2. Projection matrix

The projection parameters, defined by the field of view and the aspect ratio, are stored in the projection matrix. Therefore the viewport position can be recovered by the values from the projection matrix, from a symmetrical perspective projection.

Note the relation between projection matrix, field of view and aspect ratio:

```
prjMat[0][0] = 2*n/(r-l) = 1.0 / (tanFov * aspect);
prjMat[1][1] = 2*n/(t-b) = 1.0 / tanFov;

prjMat[2][2] = -(f+n)/(f-n)
prjMat[3][2] = -2*f*n/(f-n)
```

Recover the Z distance in view space:

```
A     = prj_mat[2][2];
B     = prj_mat[3][2];
z_ndc = 2.0 * depth - 1.0;
z_eye = B / (A + z_ndc);
```

Recover the view space position by the XY normalized device coordinates:

```
viewPos.x = z_eye * ndc_x / prjMat[0][0];
viewPos.y = z_eye * ndc_y / prjMat[1][1];
viewPos.z = -z_eye;
```

#### 3. Inverse projection matrix

Of course the viewport position can be recovered by the inverse projection matrix.

```
mat4 inversePrjMat = inverse( prjMat );
vec4 viewPosH      = inversePrjMat * vec3( ndc_x, ndc_y, 2.0 * depth - 1.0, 1.0 )
vec3 viewPos       = viewPos.xyz / viewPos.w;
```

See also the answers to the following question:

- [How to render depth linearly in modern OpenGL with gl_FragCoord.z in fragment shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh/45710371#45710371)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to make it work in the end, As its a different method from above I will detail it so anyone who sees this will have a solution.

- Pass 1: Store the depth value in view space to the gbuffer
- To re-create the (x, y, z) position in the second pass:
- Pass the horizontal and vertical field of view in radians into the shader.
- Pass the near plane distance (near) to the shader. (distance from camera position to near plane)
- Imagine a ray from the camera to the fragment position. This ray intersects the near plane at a certain position P. We have this position in the ndc space and want to compute this position in view space.
- Now, we have all the values we need in view space. We can use the law of similar triangles to find the actual fragment position P'

  ```
  P = P_ndc * near * tan(fov/2.0f) // computation is the same for x, y
  // Note that by law of similar triangles, P'.x / depth = P/near  
  P'.xy = P/near * -depth; // -depth because in opengl the camera is staring down the -z axis
  P'.z = depth;
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a deferred shader, and used this code to recalculate screen space positioning:

```
vec3 getFragmentPosition()
{
     vec4 sPos = vec4(gl_TexCoord[0].x, gl_TexCoord[0].y, texture2D(depthTex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).x, 1.0);
     sPos.z = 2.0 * sPos.z - 1.0;
     sPos = invPersp * sPos;

     return sPos.xyz / sPos.w;
}
```

where `depthTex` is the texture holding depth info, and `invPersp` is a pre-calculated inverse perspective matrix. You take the screen's fragment position, and multiply it by the inverse perspective matrix to get model-view coordinates. Then you divide by `w` to get homogenous coordinates. The multiplication by two and subtraction by one is to scale the depth from [0, 1] (as it is stored in the texture) to [-1, 1].

Also, depending on what kind of MRTs you are using, the recalculated result won't be exactly equal to the stored info, since you lose the float precision.

Comment: Is your depth texture stored in a format such that the `2*p-1` that you're doing to *all* coordinates will produce the proper value?

Comment: what space is the depth you are storing into depthTex in?

Comment: I store it, in my GBuffer shader, as `gl_FradCoord.z`.

Comment: Sorry, only the `z` portion of `sPos` should be scaled - I edited my original post.

Comment: Yes, since I'm pretty sure `gl_FragCoord` is also in view space. (Sorry I misspelled it earlier.)

Comment: why do you have to scale the depth from [0-1] to [-1, 1] ? that does not make any sense to me... some quick google-fu indicates that gl_FragCoord.z is the z value after projection, that is in [0-1] ndc? space.

Comment: You want the z value before projection, when it's solely model-view. I'm not an expert on the field, so I don't know the precise reason you need [-1, 1] rather than [0, 1].