# Transforming the screen space to world space to create a point cloud in python

Tags: python, opengl, point-clouds

I am trying to transform screen space coordinates(2D) to world space(3D) for point cloud generation in python language. Given to me are projection matrix, view matrix, and a depth image. I am trying to follow these steps: [Getting World Position from Depth Buffer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227283/getting-world-position-from-depth-buffer-value).

So far, I have come up with this code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

origin = camera[:-1]

clipSpaceLocation =[]
m_points = []

# Matrix multipication of projection and then view and finally inverse of it
IViewProj = np.linalg.inv(proj @ view)
                          
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):        
                
        # 4x1
        # depth image with grayscale values from 0-255
        clipSpaceLocation = np.array([(x / width) * 2 - 1,
                                      (y / height) * 2 - 1,
                                       depth[y,x] * 2 - 1,
                                      1])

        # 4x4 @ 4x1 -> 4x1
        worldSpaceLocation = IViewProj @ clipSpaceLocation
        # perspective division
        worldSpaceLocation /= worldSpaceLocation[-1]
        worldSpaceV3 = worldSpaceLocation[:-1]
        m_points.append(worldSpaceV3)
                   
        
m_points = np.array(m_points)
```

m_points are [xyz] position, which I am eventually plotting on point cloud but it isn't giving the correct result, it's basically giving me the point cloud of depth image. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution. If anyone is looking for the answer in Python, this is the solution:

```
@staticmethod
def read_pc_from_layers(file_cam, file_depth, file_colour):
    origin, projection, view, = read_cam_file(file_cam)
    depth = imageio.imread(file_depth)
    colour = imageio.imread(file_colour)
    i_view_projection = np.linalg.inv(view @ projection)
    width = depth.shape[1]
    height = depth.shape[0]
    vertices = []
    colours = []
    point_cloud = PointCloud()
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            #map to [0,1]
            d = depth[height - y - 1][x][0] / 255.0
            # check for valid values
            if 0.00001 < d < 0.99999999999:
                clip_space_location = np.array([(x / width) * 2 - 1, (y / height) * 2 - 1, d * 2 - 1, 1])
                world_space_location = clip_space_location @ i_view_projection
                world_space_location /= world_space_location[3]
                colours.append(colour[height - y - 1][x])
                vertices.append(world_space_location[0:3])
    point_cloud.vertices = np.asarray(vertices)
    point_cloud.colours_luminance = np.asarray(colours).astype(np.uint8)
    point_cloud.colours_labels = np.asarray(colours).astype(np.uint8)
    return point_cloud
```