# Field of view + Aspect Ratio + View Matrix from Projection Matrix (HMD OST Calibration)

Tags: opengl, matrix, aspect-ratio, perspectivecamera

I'm currently working on an Augmented reality application. The targetted device being an Optical See-though HMD I need to calibrate its display to achieve a correct registration of virtual objects. 
I used that [implementation of SPAAM](https://github.com/krm104/AndroidSPAAM/) for android to do it and the result are precise enough for my purpose.

My problem is, calibration application give in output a **4x4 <s>projection</s> matrix** I could have directly use with OpenGL for exemple. But, the Augmented Reality framework I use only accept optical calibration parameters under the format **<s>Field of View</s> some parameter + <s>Aspect Ratio</s> some parameter + 4x4 <s>View</s> matrix.**

Here is what I have :

**Correct calibration result under wrong format :**

```
 6.191399, 0.114267, -0.142429, -0.142144
-0.100027, 11.791289, 0.05604,   0.055928
 0.217304,-0.486923, -0.990243, -0.988265
 0.728104, 0.005347, -0.197072,  0.003122
```

You can take a look at the code that generate this result [here](https://github.com/krm104/AndroidSPAAM/blob/master/src/com/spaam/util/spaamutil.java).

What I understand is the Single Point Active Alignment Method produce a 3x4 matrix, then the program multiply this matrice by an orthogonal projection matrix to get the result above. Here are the param used to produce the orthogonal matrix :

```
near : 0.1, far : 100.0, right : 960, left : 0, top :  540, bottom:  0
```

**Bad calibration result under right format :**

```
Param 1 : 12.465418
Param 2 : 1.535465

 0.995903,   -0.046072,   0.077501,  0.000000   
 0.050040,    0.994671,  -0.047959,  0.000000
-0.075318,    0.051640,   0.992901,  0.000000
 114.639359, -14.115030, -24.993097, 1.000000
```

I don't have any information on how these result are obtained.

I read these parameters from binary files, and I don't know if matrices are stored in row or column major form. So the two matrices may have to be transposed.

My question is : **Is it possible, and if yes, how to get these three parameters from the <s>projection</s> first matrix I have ?**

Comment: projection matrix an view matrix are different things - see [Transform the modelMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008171/transform-the-modelmatrix/46008573#46008573).
Probably `fov = 2.0*atan(1.0/prjM[1][1])*180.0/PI; aspect = prjM[1][1]/prj[0][0]` - see [How to recover view space position given view space depth value and ndc xy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277501/how-to-recover-view-space-position-given-view-space-depth-value-and-ndc-xy/46118945#46118945)

Comment: It is possible to get that information out of the projection matrix, but you would need to know what formulae has been used to construct it.

Comment: Derp, I can't read. I didn't notice the view matrix was also there. The most you can extract from a projection matrix is fov & aspect ratio

Comment: From where do you know that the calibration result is correct?

Comment: Because once loaded in their respective framework the first result produce a good registration of virtual objects, whereas the second produce a bad registration.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is it possible, and if yes, how to get these three parameters from the projection matrix I have ?

The projection matrix and the view matrix describe completely different transformations. While the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport, the view matrix describes the direction and position from which the scene is looked at. The view matrix is defined by the camera position and the direction too the target of view and the up vector of the camera.
 (see [Transform the modelMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008171/transform-the-modelmatrix/46008573#46008573)))

This means it is not possible to get the view matrix from the projection matrix. But the camera defines a view matrix.

If the projection is perspective, then it will be possible to get the field of view angle and the aspect ratio from the projection matrix.

[image]

The Perspective Projection Matrix looks like this:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far

2*n/(r-l)      0              0               0
0              2*n/(t-b)      0               0
(r+l)/(r-l)    (t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)   -1    
0              0              -2*f*n/(f-n)    0
```

it follows:

```
aspect = w / h
tanFov = tan( fov_y * 0.5 );

p[0][0] = 2*n/(r-l) = 1.0 / (tanFov * aspect)
p[1][1] = 2*n/(t-b) = 1.0 / tanFov
```

The field of view angle along the Y-axis in degrees:

```
fov = 2.0*atan( 1.0/prjMatrix[1][1] ) * 180.0 / PI;
```

The aspect ratio:

```
aspect = prjMatrix[1][1] / prjMatrix[0][0];
```

<sub>See further the answers to the following question:

[How to render depth linearly in modern OpenGL with gl_FragCoord.z in fragment shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh/45710371#45710371)

[How to recover view space position given view space depth value and ndc xy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277501/how-to-recover-view-space-position-given-view-space-depth-value-and-ndc-xy/46118945#46118945)</sub>