# How to get world coordinates from the screen coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to get world coordinates from the screen coordinates.

This is my process.

1. Get the Screen coordinates from the mouse click
2. Multiply projection with view matrix

   ```
   FinalMatrix = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix;
   ```

3)Inverse the matrix

```
    finalMatrix = glm::inverse(finalMatrix);
```

4. Get the position in world coordinates

   ```
   glm::vec4 worldPosition = finalMatrix * glm::vec4(screenPoint.x - 1920.0 / 2.0,  -1.0 * (screenPoint.y - 1080.0 / 2.0) , screenPoint.z, 1.0);
   ```

But the final position does not match the world position of mouse click

Comment: Are you trying to do picking? (_Ie_, determine the shape that the mouse pointer is over.)

Comment: @Neil Yes i am trying to do picking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `screenPoint.xy` is the poisition of the mouse in window coordinates (pixel). And `screenPoint.z` is the depth from the depth buffer. You must transform the position to Normalized Device Cooridnates. NDC are in range (-1, -1, -1):

```cpp
glm::vec3 fC = screenPoint;
glm::vec3 ndc = glm::vec3(fC.x / 1920.0, 1.0 - fC.y / 1080.0, fC.z) * 2.0 - 1.0;
glm::vec4 worldPosition = finalMatrix * glm::vec4(ndc, 1);
```

`worldPosition` is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). You must divide it by it's `w` component to get  a [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) (see [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide)):

```cpp
glm::vec3 p = glm::vec3(worldPosition) / worldPosition.w;
```

See also [OpenGL - Mouse coordinates to Space coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749675/opengl-mouse-coordinates-to-space-coordinates/46752492#46752492).