# How to extract camera parameters from Projection matrix

Tags: javascript, three.js, projection-matrix

I have a Perspective Camera with a certain projection matrix ,I just want to extract the fow , near plane and far plane from it.
I know there is a function in Three.js :

```
.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

it creates a projection matrix based on parameters listed above, basically i want the reverse process.

Comment: https://jsantell.com/3d-projection

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182845/field-of-view-aspect-ratio-view-matrix-from-projection-matrix-hmd-ost-calib

Comment: From what I read he does not say how to calculate the near and far plane @WestLangley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved with this 3 formulas :

**fov** = 2 * atan(1/camera.projectionMatrix.elements[5]) * 180 / PI;

**near** = camera.projectionMatrix.elements[14] / (camera.projectionMatrix.elements[10] - 1.0);

**far** = camera.projectionMatrix.elements[14] / (camera.projectionMatrix.elements[10] + 1.0);

Sources :

[3D Projection](https://jsantell.com/3d-projection)

[Decompose the OpenGL projection matrix](http://lektiondestages.blogspot.com/2013/11/decompose-opengl-projection-matrix.html)

[Field of view + Aspect Ratio + View Matrix from Projection Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182845/field-of-view-aspect-ratio-view-matrix-from-projection-matrix-hmd-ost-calib)

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's anything else to extract from the matrix to completely 'clone' the camera behavior?
I did setup a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jurito/013x78n4/19/) with an example of what i want to achieve. Basically you click on the scene and it switches camera to another one created with the extracted properties, but as you see it's not working as expected..