# OpenGL not rendering figure

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, glut, pyopengl

The code below is expected to draw a snowman and then camera is controlled using keyboard keys. But it's only drawing some dots.

I tried to increase the radius of sphere but it was still not working properly. what's the problem in the code ? If it is about dimensions, then what should be the correct dimension ?

Output should look like this image -

[image: Output]

```
from __future__ import division
import time
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import sys, math

# angle of rotation for the camera direction
angle=0.0;
# actual vector representing the camera's direction
lx=0.0
lz=-1.0;
# XZ position of the camera
x=0.0
z=5.0;

def drawSnowMan():    
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    # Draw Body
    glTranslatef(0.0 ,0.75, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.75,20,20);

    # Draw Head
    glTranslatef(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.25,20,20);

    # Draw Eyes
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.05, 0.10, 0.18);
    glutSolidSphere(0.05,10,10);
    glTranslatef(-0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.05,10,10);
    glPopMatrix();

    # Draw Nose
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.5 , 0.5);
    glutSolidCone(0.08,0.5,10,2);


def renderScene():    
    global angle, lx, lz, x, z

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()

    refresh2d(width, height)

    # Set the camera
    gluLookAt(  x, 1.0, z, x+lx, 1.0,  z+lz, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0);

    # Draw ground
    glColor3f(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-100.0, 0.0, -100.0);
    glVertex3f(-100.0, 0.0,  100.0);
    glVertex3f( 100.0, 0.0,  100.0);
    glVertex3f( 100.0, 0.0, -100.0);
    glEnd();

    # Draw 36 SnowMen
    for i in range(-3,3):
        for j in range(-3, 3):
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(i*10.0,0,j * 10.0);
            drawSnowMan();
            glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();


def processSpecialKeys(key, xx, yy):    
    global angle, lx, lz, x, z

    fraction = 0.1

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT):
        angle -= 0.01
        lx = math.sin(angle);
        lz = -math.cos(angle);

    elif(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT):
        angle += 0.01
        lx = math.sin(angle);
        lz = -math.cos(angle);

    elif(key == GLUT_KEY_UP):
        x += lx * fraction;
        z += lz * fraction;

    elif(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN):
        x -= lx * fraction;
        z -= lz * fraction; 


def refresh2d(width, height):
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(-300.0, 300, -300, 300, 0.0, 10.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()


# init GLUT and create window
width = 600
height = 600

glutInit();
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse3D - GLUT Tutorial");

# register callbacks
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);

# OpenGL init
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

# enter GLUT event processing cycle
glutMainLoop();
```

Comment: But it still is not showing the output as I want.

Comment: This code is python version of this code - http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard-example-moving-around-the-world/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) specifies the Orthographic Projection. A field of view from -300.0 to 300.0 is much to wide for your geometry, because all your geometry is in [-1.0, 1.0].

If you switch to

```
glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 10.0)
```

then you will see a snowman, perfectly fit into your viewport.

I recommend to use [Perspective Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). This mean you have to set up a perspective projection matrix.

Note, the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. At Orthographic Projection the coordinates in the eye space are linearly mapped. But at Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport.

This means that you have to delete `glOrtho(-300.0, 300, -300, 300, 0.0, 10.0)`. Use [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) instead. e.g.:

```
gluPerspective(45.0, width/height, 0.5, 10.0)
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Why the code given here http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard-example-moving-around-the-world/ doesn't require these matrices?

Comment: @AdarshJain Of course it is required. The code in the tutorial is not complete. See the 20. response (of "Glenn") at the [tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard-example-moving-around-the-world/) (at the end of the page).

Comment: oh yes, I found it.                                                                                 
Why the angle 45 is used in gluPerspective?

Comment: @AdarshJain That is the field of view angle of the perspective camera. See [Calculating frustum FOV for a PerspectiveCamera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164180/calculating-frustum-fov-for-a-perspectivecamera/46169212#46169212) and [Field of view + Aspect Ratio + View Matrix from Projection Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182845/field-of-view-aspect-ratio-view-matrix-from-projection-matrix-hmd-ost-calib/46195462#46195462)

Comment: Now most of the things are clear. Thanks for the help @Rabbid76 