# Reading depth buffer with PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

Basically, I'm trying to extract a depth map (by this I mean a matrix with z corresponding to z-coordinates for vertices in `GL.glVertex3dv(vertex)` call - obviously, interpolated for plane pixels) after rendering a model (script is loading the model from file with path specified as the first command line argument).

There are several questions which come to mind:

- why `glReadPixels` call returns a numpy array with shape `(width, shape)`, instead of `(height, width)`?
- why it returns some trash, not connected to the rendered model?
- is there an easy way to get z-coordinates on OpenGL legacy code with PyOpenGL framework?
- is it correct that maximum I can get here is some array with range `[0; 1]`, basically is some fraction between zNear and zFar (and normalized by glReadPixels, for whatever reason)?

The code itself:

```
import sys
import argparse
import pyassimp
from pyassimp.postprocess import aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices, aiProcess_Triangulate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple
from OpenGL import GL, GLUT

Mesh = namedtuple('Mesh', ('vertices', 'faces'))

def load_mesh(filename):
    scene = pyassimp.load(filename, processing=aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_Triangulate)
    mesh = scene.mMeshes[0].contents

    def get_vector_array(vector):
        return [vector.x, vector.y, vector.z]

    def get_face_array(face):
        return [face.mIndices[i] for i in xrange(face.mNumIndices)]

    vertices = np.array([get_vector_array(mesh.mVertices[i]) for i in xrange(mesh.mNumVertices)])
    faces = np.array([get_face_array(mesh.mFaces[i]) for i in xrange(mesh.mNumFaces)])

    pyassimp.release(scene)

    return Mesh(vertices, faces)


def load_ortho():
    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION)
    GL.glLoadIdentity()
    GL.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1)
    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW)
    GL.glLoadIdentity()


mesh = None
width, height = 1920, 1080

def draw_mesh():
    global mesh, width, height
    GL.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
    GL.glClearDepth(0.5)
    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    GL.glDepthMask(GL.GL_TRUE)
    load_ortho()
    for face in mesh.faces:
        GL.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON)
        for vertex in mesh.vertices[face]:
            GL.glVertex3dv(vertex)
        GL.glEnd()
    GLUT.glutSwapBuffers()
    d = GL.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL.GL_FLOAT)
    plt.imshow(d)
    plt.show()


def reshape(w, h):
    GL.glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
    GLUT.glutDisplayFunc(draw_mesh)
    GLUT.glutPostRedisplay()


def init(width, height):
    GLUT.glutInit(sys.argv)
    GLUT.glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT.GLUT_RGBA | GLUT.GLUT_DOUBLE)
    GLUT.glutInitWindowSize(width, height)
    GLUT.glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
    GLUT.glutCreateWindow("test")
    # GLUT.glutDisplayFunc(draw_mesh)
    # GLUT.glutIdleFunc(draw_mesh)
    GLUT.glutReshapeFunc(reshape)
    GLUT.glutIdleFunc(GLUT.glutPostRedisplay)

    def keyPressed(self, *args):
        if args[0] == '\033':
            sys.exit()
    GLUT.glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Test on extracting depth while rendering a model with PyOpenGL")
    parser.add_argument("model", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    global mesh
    mesh = load_mesh(args.model)

    init(width, height)
    draw_mesh()
```

The model file I personally used for testing: [bunny.obj](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Data/Meshes/bunny.obj)
The snippet's result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCd5C.png)

Comment: At orthographic projection the Z-coorinate is linaer mapped to the depth value (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh/45710371#45710371)). The depth value is in range [0.0, 1.0]. So the Z-coordinate in view space is `z = -near - depth*(far-near)`. In your case it is `z = 1 - 2*depth;`. Because you have not set any model view matrix (`GL_MODELVIEW`), the view space is equal the world space.

Comment: Also possibly silly issue: it looks like you aren't calling `glClear` anywhere to clear the color and depth buffers. `glClearColor` and `glClearDepth` just set the values for what clearing should do, but do not actually perform clearing of the buffers themselves. This might explain the "trash" you are seeing.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon This didn't help. Updated the snippet accordingly. Also added snippet's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code gave me some `"Invalid Operation Error: 1282"` messages for the `glReadPixels` call. Instead, here is a simple demo I just wrote that shows how to obtain the color and the depth buffer from OpenGL for a rendered triangle. What I do here is bind an FBO (framebuffer object) to the screen with the desired texture attachments (for receiving the color and depth data). I then read out the data from the GPU using `glGetTexImage`. Using textures might not be the fastest approach, but this is pretty simple and should work nicely. Let me know if anything in this is unclear and I will elaborate on it.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import numpy as np
import sys

def draw_scene():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0)
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0)
    glVertex3f(0, 1, 0)
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1)
    glVertex3f(1, -1, 0)
    glEnd()

def draw_texture():
    global color_texture
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_texture)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
    glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0)
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 0)
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 0)
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
    glVertex3f(1, -1, 0)
    glEnd()
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

def update_display():
    global fbo, color_texture, depth_texture

    #Render the scene to an offscreen FBO
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo)
    draw_scene()
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

    #Then render the results of the color texture attached to the FBO to the screen
    draw_texture()

    #Obtain the color data in a numpy array
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_texture)
    color_str = glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    color_data = np.fromstring(color_str, dtype=np.uint8)

    #Obtain the depth data in a numpy array
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture)
    depth_str = glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    depth_data = np.fromstring(depth_str, dtype=np.float32)
    print(np.min(depth_data), np.max(depth_data))#This is just to show the normalized range of depth values obtained

    glutSwapBuffers()

width, height = 800, 600
fbo = None
color_texture = None
depth_texture = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit([])
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE)
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height)
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle Test")

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)#not needed if using shaders...
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    color_texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_texture)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, None)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    depth_texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, None)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    fbo = glGenFramebuffers(1)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo)
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_texture, 0)
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture, 0)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

    glutDisplayFunc(update_display)
    glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay)
    glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: I think your answer is not applicable:
1) drawing is 2D only, no depth range present.
2) did you try to render model in such a way?
Sorry, didn't have time to check your approach thoroughly yet (and apply it to my task). 
Another question: what platform did you run my snippet on (that it failed with runtime error)?

Comment: @AndreyKravtsun 1) Even though the drawing is 2D, it still should be relevant. If you look at the contents of the `depth_data`, you can see both the background depth and the triangle depth. I just chose a 2D triangle since that was a simple shape to render in a very minimal amount of lines. Feel free to change the z-indices of the triangle and see the values in the depth texture. 2) Model should work just fine too, just have not installed the `Assimp` library on my laptop. 3) Using LinuxMint 18.3 on my laptop.

Comment: But one of the questions remains, how does that happen that pixel reading functions return wrong dimensions (width and height are swapped?). For example, in your code snippet `depth_str = glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)` depth_str.shape == (800, 600), according to debug output.

Comment: @AndreyKravtsun That is a great point! From the manual docstring associated with pyopengl's glGetTexImage (see [here](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGetTexImage.html)), it appears that it treats `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` data differently (by leaving it alone as a byte array) from other kinds of data (which it processes behind the scenes into a numpy array). I suspect that they "flip" the data so that indexing by `depth_str[x_coordinate, y_coordinate]` is "intuitive". The `OpenGL/images.py` source code on the pyopengl github is not easy to grok.