# Mouse position on (OpenGL) scene

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, pyopengl

I'm trying to get the mouse coordinate on OpenGL scene.
My Code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import (QColor)
from PySide.QtCore import (Qt, QSize)
from PySide.QtOpenGL import (QGLWidget)
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

class QGL(QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._pan_valid = False

        super(QGL, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.ClickFocus)

        self.local_translate = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.zoomVal = 1.2

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(50, 50)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(800, 800)

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.qglClearColor(QColor.fromCmykF(0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.882))
        glViewport( 0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
        glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
        glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH, GL_LINE_WIDTH, GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE)
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT,  GL_NICEST)
        glDepthRange (0.1, 1.0)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gluOrtho2D(-self.zoomVal, +self.zoomVal, -self.zoomVal, +self.zoomVal)
        glLoadIdentity()

        genList = glGenLists(1)
        glNewList(genList, GL_COMPILE)

        vertices = [
            (0,0,0),
            (0.5,0,0),
            (0.5,0.5,0),
            (0,0.5,0)
        ]

        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        self.qglColor(QColor(0,255,255))
        for vertex in vertices:
            glVertex3fv(vertex)
        glEnd()

        glEndList()
        glCallList(genList)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print event.pos()
        print self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
```

when I do this:

```
print event.pos()
```

it will give me the mouse position on the window.

and when I do this:

```
print self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
```

it will give me the mouse position on the monitor.

How can I get the mouse position on the scene?
I'm using 2D viewport (`gluOrtho2D`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a convenient built-in function for this, but it should be trivial to calculate, especially given that this is a 2D, orthographic scene. You know the size of the window in pixels, and you know where in that window the user clicked, given whatever `event.pos()` returns (also in pixels). What needs to happen then is that you need to map that range in pixels to your range specified in your `gluOrtho2D` call. The following code could be adapted as you see fit:

```
#specifying a bunch of example values
zoom_val = 1.2
window_size = (800, 600)
mouse_pos = (300, 150)
ortho_2d = (-zoom_val, +zoom_val, -zoom_val, +zoom_val)

#First, calculate the "normalized" mouse coordinates by dividing by window_size
mouse_norm_x = mouse_pos[0] / window_size[0]
mouse_norm_y = mouse_pos[1] / window_size[1]

#Now map those coordinates to your orthographic projection range
mouse_ortho_x = (mouse_norm_x * (ortho_2d[1] - ortho_2d[0])) + ortho_2d[0]
mouse_ortho_y = (mouse_norm_y * (ortho_2d[3] - ortho_2d[2])) + ortho_2d[2]
mouse_ortho = (mouse_ortho_x, mouse_ortho_y)
print(mouse_ortho)
```

Getting the z-coordinate is trickier. I would suggest reading up on the concept of "mouse-picking" for that. You would need to get the depth buffer, store its results in a texture, and sample the mouse coordinate at the appropriate location in that texture to get the z-coordinate. You can combine these two answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187981/reading-depth-buffer-with-pyopengl/48243123#48243123), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231633/using-glfw-window-inside-pyqt-window/46259752#46259752)) I have previously written for other questions together to get something working. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I see... yeah, that works perfectly, just that when dividing `mouse_pos[0] / window_size[0]` I changed it to `float(mouse_pos[0]) / float(self.width())` and `float(mouse_pos[1]) / float(self.height())`.

Comment: also, yeah, I saw an article about `Mouse Picking with Ray Casting`, but I don't need 3 dimensions yet, probably I'll consider it sometimes in future.