# Three.js MeshDepthMaterial not calculating as expected - too dark

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use Three.js's MeshDepthMaterial, however it is not working quite how I am expecting. Maybe I misunderstand how the material is supposed to work, but I'd assume that it determines "how white" the material is at a given point using the camera's near and far settings from a given camera position. So if my camera is at (0, 0, 0) with a near of 1 and a far of 1000, and I have a cube place at (0, 0, -2), I'd assume that the cube would be very white (1 - .002 = 99.8% whiteness).

However, that has not been the case. Using a near and far of 1 and 10 respectively, with the back cube placed approximately 10 units away from the camera, [this is how the material renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtLIb.png).

As you can see, the material for each cube is nearly all black, despite the nearest cube being 4 units closer.

[As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaQYZ.png), I have to get extremely close to the cube to see strong whiteness, and even then, the far corners of the cube which are not even 1 unit away are strongly gray.

These results also remain constant if I change the far to 1000 instead of 10.

Am I misunderstanding how MeshDepthMaterial works? Here's my code:

```
renderer: new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antailias:true, logarithmicDepthBuffer: true}),
scene: new THREE.Scene(),
camera: new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10)

....

this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
this.renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x00000, 1.0));
this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
this.scene.overrideMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial();

this.camera.position.z = 4;

....

this.createCube(-3, 0, -4, "#FF1215");
this.createCube(0, 0, -2);
this.createCube(2, 0, 0, "#FF7232");
```

Where the parameters for createCube are the positions

Comment: At perspective projection the depth is not linear. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh/45710371#45710371). You've to push the near plane as close to the geometry as possible, to get a "white" object.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `logarithmicDepthBuffer: true`, which changes the depth function to look more like this:

[image]

As you can see with a log function, you need to go really far down the x-axis (or bring the camera really close to the geometry) for the brightness to approach 1, since it's not a linear function. From your description, it sounds like you're expecting a linear depth buffer, which you can tell the renderer to use by setting:

`logarithmicDepthBuffer: false`

Or you can simply omit this option from the constructor, since linear depth is the default.

Comment: That makes sense, but unfortunately even with it disabled, I still have the same issues as seen in this image: https://i.imgur.com/GK83OcM.png, with the same settings as above (1 as near, 1000 as far). The back cube is nearly completely black despite being set just a few units from the near setting of the frustum. Unless I have to explicitly set a parameter to use linear depth, I'm not sure what else to try

Comment: Any chance you can show a live example, maybe via https://codepen.io/ ? I don't know what's going on inside `createCube()`. It could be some odd scaling inside that method, or it could be something else entirely.

Comment: Of course, for whatever reason the results are even more extreme in the codepen (both using r107). https://codepen.io/josephoneill/pen/yLBVKqq. I'm actually using Vue in the application I'm testing right now, all the rendering code being found here: https://pastebin.com/Abj8Lr2W

Comment: You might get slightly better results if you use `near: 1` and `far: 1000` [as you can see here](https://imgur.com/a/LzDSnfZ). However, you can only get a linear depth shading with an `OrthographicCamera`, as Rabbid76 explained in [his link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh/45710371#45710371). If you want linear shading with a `PerspectiveCamera`, you'll need to write your own material with custom shaders.