# confusion on openGL's camera and camera space transformation

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, transformation

While specifying the `model-view` transformation we need three vectors that define the camera's local axes, the `direction vector`(where the camera points) , the `up vector` and the camera's `right vector`, in these 3 axes the `direction vector` is the camera's local Z axis.

[The author at learnopengl.com mentions](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera) in the camera direction unit of this section:

> For the view matrix's coordinate system we want its z-axis to be positive and because **by default (in OpenGL) the camera points towards the negative z-axis** we want to negate the direction vector.

My question is thus:

1. We formulate the view matrix and explicitly apply the transformation
   in the shader(passing the view matrix or lookAt matrix) as a
   uniform, so *isn't the camera created by us?* It's not like OpenGL
   provides us with a default camera object for us to work with, so how
   does this ***default camera even come from? We could assume the axes
   of our coordinate space pointing any direction right?***

Comment: Try to look up for "left/right handed coordinate system" on the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We formulate the view matrix and explicitly apply the transformation
>   in the shader(passing the view matrix or lookAt matrix) as a uniform,
>   so isn't the camera created by us?

Yes, exactly. And it was the same way even before shaders. There are just coordinate transformations, if we interpret that as a "camera" is completely up to us.

> It's not like OpenGL provides us with a default camera object for us
>   to work with, so how does this default camera even come from?

That tutorial is quite imprecise here.However, there were some default *conventions* in legacy OpenGL, but these were only conventions, and never strictly required to be used. Some of the legacy OpenGL functions were designed with those
conventions in mind, though. The general idea was that the user uses a right-handed eye space, where x points to the right, y upwards and z outside of the screen towards the viewer, and therefore `-z` being the lookat direction. The old `gluLookat()` function follows these conventions.

And also the old functions for creating projection matrices adhere to this: `glFrustum()`, `glOrtho()`, `gluPerspecitve()` all take `near` and `far` as positive distances into viewing direction, but use `z_eye = -near` for the near plane, and `z_eye = -far` for the far plane, respectively. They also set up the lower row to be `0,0,-1,0`, so we end up doing the perspetive divide by `-z_eye` and get a left-handed NDC coordinate system by that (where `z_ndc` points into the screen now).

Note that the matrix functions in `glm` are modeled to follow these conventions too, but you will also find functions suffixed with the name `LH` and `RH` so you can choose the convention you like.

> We could assume the axes of our coordinate space pointing any direction right?

Yes. However, the *clip space* (which `gl_Position` vertex shader output is in) is defined by the GL: the rasterizer will always use the `x` derived from `x_cip/w_clip` and `y` derived from `y_clip/w_clip` , with `x` being horizontal, and `y` the vertical dimension. The `z` dimension is only used for depth testing, and if that is pointing into the screen our out of it is ultimately your choice again (you can switch the depth test comparison direction, or the `glDepthRange`, or both). The GPU will not care what you use inbetween at all, so for *object space*, *world space*  and _eye_space_, you can use whatever conventions you like, or you can make up completely different spaces if that suits your needs better than the traditional model.

Comment: so would the result be exactly the same if we didn't negate the z-axis for the view matrix? I mean one would expect the camera looking away from the target if the axis flipped right?

Comment: If you flip your eye space z **and** adjust the projection matrix accordingly, the end results will be the same, yes.

Comment: "-z being the lookat direction" would mean the view space if right handed, you've mentioned it as left handed

Comment: @juztcode Yes, you were correct, I mixed up the left-handed and right-handed in my description, fixed this now. However, you can't conclude handedness from "-z being the lookat direction". You can define the camera to look at `(0,0,-1)` in a right-handed space, as well as in a left-handed one. You could also define the eye space as something where the camera/eye is placed at `(1349, -0.125, sqrt(2))`, looking at `(-pi, e, 1/3)` direction. That would be just a convention, and the handedness of that space would be _another_ convention.

Answer (score 2):

At the end everything what is in 3 dimensional normalized device space is projected on the 2 dimensional viewport. The normalized device space is a cube with the left, bottom, near of (-1, -1, -1) and right, top, far of (1, 1, 1).
All the transformations which transform vertex coordinates to [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) clipspace coordinates ([`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_Position.xhtml)) respectively [cartesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) normalized device space coordinates are up to you.
(The normalized device coordinates are the clip space coordinates divide by the `w` component of the clip coordinates. This is called [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide))

The normalized device space is a left handed system (see [Left- vs. Right-handed coordinate systems](https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html) respectively [Right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)). Usually we want to use a right handed system. So at some point the cooridantes have to be transformed from a right handed to a left handed system. In common that is done by the projection matrix, which inverts (mirrors) the Z-axis.

Anyway, there's absolutely no necessity that *"by default (in OpenGL) the camera points towards the negative z-axis"*. It is a matter of specification, but in common a view coordinate system like that is used.

---

<sub>See further [Why is the z coordinate flipped after multiplying with a matrix in GLSL - OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60195019/why-is-the-z-coordinate-flipped-after-multiplying-with-a-matrix-in-glsl-opengl/60195132#60195132)</sub>

Comment: so would the result be exactly the same if we didn't negate the z-axis for the view matrix? I mean one would expect the camera looking away from the target if the axis flipped right?